# Evolution broken until system restart

Tags: suspend, email, evolution

When I restart my system, email with evolution works fine. At some point (usually when suspending and moving from office to home), all or some email accounts will stop working. I can sometimes receive but not send messages, sometimes neither receive nor send messages. The operations time out, or I get a '... does not support asking for credentials' message after a minute of trying to send the email. When I do a system restart, everything works fine again.

I have gmail, IMAP, and exchange accounts. The gmail and exchange is registered as online accounts.

What may be going on here? How to start tackling the problem, what additional information might be helpful, and how to collect it? Might there be a workaround, forcing Ubuntu to log in and out again from all accounts, without closing my other running apps?

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, Evolution 3.36.5-0ubuntu1

Thanks in advance for any pointers or help

Peter

Comment: Thank you for this constructive comment. But the online accounts feature to which this problem seems related looks very tightly integrated into Ubuntu to me. Would it be an evolution only problem, restarting evolution would likely fix it, which it doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question... The comment I made is delete now.